# Como adicionar RowDetails em WPF - XAML

Tags: front-end, wpf, xaml, back-end

Tenho o seguinte código em UserControl1.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SampleCsWinForms.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleCsWinForms"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" Width="380">
    <Grid Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" OpacityMask="Black" Background="#FF4D4D4D" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="Structure Layer Attributes" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" FontFamily="Courier" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="12" Background="#FF4D4D4D" Width="380" BorderBrush="#FFB5B5B5"/>
            <TabControl VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="tabControl" Background="#FF4D4D4D" BorderBrush="#FF545454" >
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF646464"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Style>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="#4D4D4D"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="#FF545454"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" 
                                Value="0, 0, 0, 1"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                                Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" 
                                Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" 
                                Value="25"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="#4D4D4D"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
                                Value="#4D4D4D"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" 
                                Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
                    </Style>


                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                <GradientStop Color="#4D4D4D" Offset="0.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#4D4D4D" Offset="1.0"/>
                            </GradientStopCollection>
                        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="simpleTI" TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Name="Border" 
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" 
                            Background="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
                            CornerRadius="0" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" Margin="5,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TabControl.Resources>


                <TabItem  MaxWidth="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF4D4D4D" Template="{StaticResource simpleTI}" BorderBrush="#FF4D4D4D" Margin="-2,0,0,0" >
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Image x:Name="surface" Source="/SampleCsWinForms;component/Resources/Surface_Icon.png" Width="18" Height="18" Margin="5"/>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <Expander Name="ExpanderControl" Header="Permanent Area Load"  Foreground="White"  FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="DimGray" Background="Gray" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3">
                        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="550" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" >
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4D4D4D" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ScrollViewer.Resources>
                                <DataGrid Name="DataGridControl" BorderBrush="#FF484848"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" Background="#00000000" SelectionChanged="DataGridControl_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF5A5A5A" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF5A5A5A" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">                               
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4D4D4D"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4D4D4D"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                                        <Border Name="DGR_Border" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                                                
                                                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                                            
                                                        </Border>
                                                        
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF404040"/>
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">

                                                                <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1C7D1C"/>
                                                            </Trigger>

                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                      
                                            <StackPanel Background="Yellow">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                                
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                    <DataGrid.Columns >
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <WrapPanel>
                                                        <Path Fill="DarkSeaGreen" Data="M0,0 L5,5 L0,10 L2.5,5 Z" Margin="5,7,0,0">
                                                            <Path.Style>
                                                                <Style TargetType="Path">
                                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                                </Style>
                                                            </Path.Style>
                                                        </Path>
                                                    </WrapPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="cm" Width="40" CanUserSort="False" CanUserResize="True" CanUserReorder="False">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding cm}" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding cm, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="22" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="#4D4D4D"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Material" Width="*">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Material}" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Material, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="22" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="#FF404040" BorderBrush="#FF404040"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Kg/m²" Width="40">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding KgM2Cm}" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding KgM2Cm, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="22" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="#4D4D4D"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>                                 
                                </DataGrid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem  MaxWidth="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF4D4D4D" Template="{StaticResource simpleTI}" BorderBrush="#FF4D4D4D" Margin="-2,0,0,0" >
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Image x:Name="support1" Source="/SampleCsWinForms;component/Resources/Capa_Sup_Icon.png" Width="18" Height="18" Margin="5"/>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>

            </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Em UserControl1.xaml.cs tenho o seguinte código:

```cs
namespace SampleCsWinForms
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("3d3db472-509d-41c5-97e3-2890c5fb9827")]
    /// <summary>
    /// Interação lógica para UserControl1.xam
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            /////////////////////////
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using (var stream1 = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SampleCsWinForms.Resources.Surface_Icon.png"))
            using (var stream2 = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SampleCsWinForms.Resources.Capa_Sup_Icon.png"))

            {
                if (stream1 != null && stream2 != null)
                {
                    var image1 = new Bitmap(stream1);
                    var image2 = new Bitmap(stream2);


                    // Atribui as imagens aos controles de imagem correspondentes
                    surface.Source = ImageSourceFromBitmap(image1);
                    support1.Source = ImageSourceFromBitmap(image2);

                }
            }

            /////////////////////////////
            List<MyData> dataList = new List<MyData>
        {
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Gesso", KgM2Cm = "7.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Compensado", KgM2Cm = "7.5" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Ripado de Madeira", KgM2Cm = "10.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Placa Cimentícia", KgM2Cm = "17.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Painel Wall", KgM2Cm = "7.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Entarugamento Médio DE", KgM2Cm = "1.25" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Lã de Rocha", KgM2Cm = "2.5" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Isopor", KgM2Cm = "0.1" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "OSB", KgM2Cm = "7.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Manta Acústica EPS", KgM2Cm = "30.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Manta Impermeabilizante EVA/TPO", KgM2Cm = "5.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Cinasita", KgM2Cm = "4.5" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Manta Geodrenante + Substrato Skygarden", KgM2Cm = "10.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Deck de Madeira", KgM2Cm = "20.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Policarbonato", KgM2Cm = "12.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Vidro", KgM2Cm = "24.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Taubilha", KgM2Cm = "10.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Telha Termoacústica", KgM2Cm = "20.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Telha Aço Singela", KgM2Cm = "14.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Equipamento Solar", KgM2Cm = "15.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Telha Cerâmica", KgM2Cm = "70.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Telha Shingle", KgM2Cm = "18.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Manta Acústica", KgM2Cm = "3.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Manta Asfáltica", KgM2Cm = "20.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Concreto Leve (1400kg/m³)", KgM2Cm = "14.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Concreto", KgM2Cm = "25.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Argamassa", KgM2Cm = "21.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Assoalho de Madeira", KgM2Cm = "10.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Piso Cerâmico", KgM2Cm = "18.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Placa Concresteel", KgM2Cm = "24.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Paredes com PP<35kg/m²", KgM2Cm = "50.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Paredes com PP<65kg/m²", KgM2Cm = "75.0" },
            new MyData { cm = "0", Material = "Paredes com PP<100kg/m²", KgM2Cm = "100.0" }

        };
            DataGridControl.SelectionChanged += DataGridControl_SelectionChanged;
            DataGridControl.ItemsSource = dataList;

        }



        private static BitmapImage ImageSourceFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.Position = 0;
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
            }
            return bitmapImage;
        }

        private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExpanderControl_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TabControl_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DataGridControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verifica se uma linha foi selecionada
            if (DataGridControl.SelectedItem is MyData selectedItem)
            {
                // Obtém o índice da linha selecionada
                int selectedIndex = DataGridControl.SelectedIndex;

                // Verifica se a linha selecionada é uma das linhas que devem exibir os detalhes
                int[] linhasExibirDetalhes = { 9, 10, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 30, 31, 32 };
                if (linhasExibirDetalhes.Contains(selectedIndex))
                {
                    // Exibe o RowDetails da linha selecionada
                    DataGridControl.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Oculta o RowDetails das outras linhas
                    DataGridControl.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Em uma classe que criei chamada MyData.CS tenho isso:

```cs
    namespace SampleCsWinForms
    {
        public class MyData
        {
            public string cm { get; set; }
            public string Material { get; set; }
            public string KgM2Cm { get; set; }
            public string Description
            {
                get
                {
                    return String.Format("Note that this item is a unit, that is, it represents a quantity and not a measurement in centimeters. Make sure to verify that the information in this item has been filled in correctly.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Estou com o seguinte problema, o código no visual studio não aparece nenhum erro, ele roda normal, porém ao selecionar os itens na tabela não aparece a linha de detalhes. Talvez de alguma forma DataGridRow esteja entrando em conflito com RowDetails. De qualquer forma, o meu objetivo é, ao selecionar determinados itens da tabela gostaria que aparecesse uma linha de detalhe, alguém consegue me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em no seu `DataGrid.RowStyle`, em `SelectiveScrollingGrid`.
Faltou a definição de `DataGridDetailsPresenter`.

```html
<SelectiveScrollingGrid>

    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>

    <!-- Faltou isso aqui...  -->
    <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                              SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                              Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                              
</SelectiveScrollingGrid>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).